# CSS fixed position footer stacks when printing

Tags: html, css

Maybe someone can explain what's going on here, because I've been racking my brain for a while on this and all of my web searching has failed to turn up a functional answer.  Here's a sample HTML page with automatically generated page numbers:

```js
function pageCount() {
  console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('page').length);
  return document.getElementsByClassName('page').length;
}
document.querySelectorAll(".total").forEach(function(el, i) {
  el.innerHTML = pageCount();
});
```

```css
.page {
  width: 8in;
  height: 1in;
  padding: 0em;
  margin-top: .5in;
  margin-left: 0in;
  margin-right: 0in;
  margin-bottom: 0.25in;
}

body {
  color: black;
  counter-reset: pagen;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.footer {
  counter-increment: pagen;
  margin: auto;
  width: 8in;
  display: table;
}

#footer-left:before {
  content: "Page " counter(pagen) " of ";
}

.ptable {
  page-break-before: always;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}

@media print {
  .footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style></style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="footer">
      <div id="footer-left"><span class="total"></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <table class="ptable"></table>
    <div class="footer">
      <div id="footer-left"><span class="total"></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <table class="ptable"></table>
    <div class="footer">
      <div id="footer-left"><span class="total"></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script></script>
</html>
```

On screen, we see our separate footer fields showing the page number.  When you go to print it, however, all of the footers end up stacking on top of each other in one giant mess.  `position: fixed; bottom: 0;` causes the footer elements to stack up on top of each other, changing `fixed` to `absolute` means they get stacked on page 1 only and changing to `relative` just moves the footer to the bottom of the content.  Any suggestions on how to correct this behavior?  Browser used for testing is Chrome.

Comment: Tried `position: absolute;` ?

Comment: Do you want the footer stick to the bottom with no overlap?

Comment: @AjitZero yes, it's in the bottom of my comments there.  Absolute causes the same issue, just limited to page 1 (pages 2 & 3 don't get the footer with absolute).

Comment: @RishabhdevTyagi Yes the footer needs to go down to the bottom of the page where it belongs, regardless of how much content is on the page, and not have all footer elements stacking on top of each other.

Comment: The id footer-left must be unique.

Comment: I have added an answer.Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

The position:fixed; is defined in browser's css.But you can override it.That means console is not the part of website.The javascript is run on that.You have to add style for every browser's console.

```js
function pageCount() {
  console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('page').length);
  return document.getElementsByClassName('page').length;
}
document.querySelectorAll(".total").forEach(function(el, i) {
  el.innerHTML = pageCount();
});
```

```css
.page {
  width: 8in;
  height: 1in;
  padding: 0em;
  margin-top: .5in;
  margin-left: 0in;
  margin-right: 0in;
  margin-bottom: 0.25in;
}

body {
  color: black;
  counter-reset: pagen;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.footer {
  position:fixed;
  margin-top:340px;
  width: 8in;
   
}

#footer-left:before {
  content: "Page " counter(pagen) " of ";
}

.ptable {
  page-break-before: always;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}

@media print {
  .footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style></style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="footer">
      <div id="footer-left"><span class="total"></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <table class="ptable"></table>
    <div class="footer">
      <div id="footer-left"><span class="total"></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <table class="ptable"></table>
    <div class="footer">
      <div id="footer-left"><span class="total"></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script></script>
</html>
```

Comment: The browser isn't getting the CSS for position from anywhere else in the document.  All styling is defined inline, so without the `position: fixed;` under `@media print` the footer defaults to relative and ends up at the top of each page.

Comment: Still causes the print issue in my local test file.

Comment: please give me the link of site

Comment: It's not a site.  It's a local page.  Go back into the revisions of the first post, pull the non-snippet version of the html page, dump into a text editor and save as html, then open in your browser.  When you go to the print preview of the page, you'll see what I'm talking about.  You can also reassemble it by copying the snippet sections and putting the css between the style tags shown in the html code, and the script between the script tags at the bottom, then save and open in your browser as above.

Comment: I have edited the answer.Please check it.Run it full screen or as a local page.

Comment: I have found a way to stick the footer to the bottom of the page by setting position:fixed; and margin-top:340px;

Comment: It's moved the footer down on screen which will interfere with content.  The stacking issue during print remains.  Also, this latest correction has now caused the page increment to break, so each page is displaying 0 of 3.  The target here is page content not affected, pages individually numbered (on screen this will look like one single continuous page), and print preview correctly renders the footer text at the bottom of each page without any layering or duplication.  Backing up to before the counter broke, the existing print would layer all footers on top of each other on each page.